# Распарсить xml файл при помощи Луа

Tags: xml, парсер, lua

Нужно распарсить xml файл (извлеченный из docx) при помощи Луа.
Пробовал luaxml но не получилось (а может и не сумел), у меня luaxml не видит структуру с двоеточиями...
Условный пример из zbstudio в аттаче:
[image: Условный пример из zbstudio:]

Comment: Глянь https://github.com/stevedonovan/LuaExpatUtils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот можно так с уровнями и узлами и без рекурсии:

```
    local str_xml = [[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <w:document xmlns:w=".....">
        <w:body  att="xxx">
            <w:p att="yyy1">
                <w:r att="zzz">
                    <w:t>Hello world!</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
            <w:p att="yyy2">
            </w:p>
        </w:body>
    </w:document>
    ]]

require 'luaxml'

local xtable = xml.eval(str_xml)

if type(xtable)=='table' then
        for i=1,#xtable  do
          local nodeL1 = xtable[i]

          if nodeL1[0] == 'w:body' then
                 print(nodeL1.att)
                  local level1=1
                   while nodeL1[level1] do      
                         if nodeL1[level1][0]  == 'w:p' then   
                              print("L1",nodeL1[level1].att)  
                              local nodeL2 =  nodeL1[level1]
                              local level2=1
                               while nodeL2[level2] do
                                      if  nodeL2[level2][0]  == 'w:r' then  
                                          print("L2",nodeL2[level2].att)
                                          local nodeL3 =  nodeL2[level2]
                                          local level3=1
                                           while nodeL3[level3] do
                                                  if  nodeL3[level3][0]  == 'w:t' then 
                                                           print("L3",nodeL3[level3][1])
                                                           --- и т.д.                                                
                                                  end
                                                  level3=level3+1
                                           end 
                                      end
                                      level2=level2+1
                                end
                         end
                         level1=level1+1             
                   end  
             end
        end
end
```

можно и через функцию с рекурсивными вызовами сделать при желании